# How do I access JavaScript this from ScriptSharp?

Tags: this, script#

I'm trying to do the following.

```
var handler = e => { handle(); item.Unbind("event", this); }
item.Bind("event", handler);
```

In JavaScript this would properly work, but ScriptSharp replaces JavaScript's this with reference to the instance of class containing method with that code. How do I avoid this behavior and get a reference to the lambda from the lambda itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it (assuming Bind takes a delegate with the signature of an Action):

```
SomeObject item = ...;
Action handler = null;

handler = delegate() {
   // do something ... eg. call Handle();
   item.Unbind("event", handler);
};
item.Bind("event", handler);
```

Also, see this question: [How to write a function in script# to be called with any object as this, not just with the instance of the class in which it is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135498/how-to-write-a-function-in-script-to-be-called-with-any-object-as-this-not-jus) for a technique for writing code that generates a "this" reference in script.