# How to access html function from Script# code?

Tags: javascript, html, script#

In Script# how do I access a function defined in the html on the page?

On the html page is this pre-existing function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function makeStuffHappen(selector)
    {
           alert('stuff happening');
    }
</script>
<div id='#usefulplace'></div>
```

I load up the generated script from scriptsharp and need access to the "Global" makeStuffHappen function in that generated script. Basically, from Scriptsharp I need to be able to call the function 
`makeStuffHappen("#usefulplace");`

How can I call makeStuffHappen from inside the scriptsharp?

Comment: Please add more context, such as how does scriptsharp and that function coincide? Is it a defined method of the same class? If not, where does that page come from, and what code is currently used to interact with that page? Also, im not too familiar with script# myself, but this maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149273/how-do-i-access-javascript-this-from-scriptsharp. And maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135498/how-to-write-a-function-in-script-to-be-called-with-any-object-as-this-not-jus

Comment: I actually read through both of those before posting the question, I'll add context as I can but the gist is I'm loading the javascript from scriptsharp onto the page and need it to call an already defined pure (not scriptsharp) function on the page

Comment: Along with the downvote could whoever downvoted leave a comment so I know how to improve my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I created a scriptsharp class file and did IgnoreNamespace, Imported, and ScriptAlias all three to get it to map to the function in the html, as follows:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [Imported]
    public static class ImportedPageFunctions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selector"></param>
        [ScriptAlias("makeStuffHappen")]
        public static void makeStuffHappen(string selector)
        {

        }
    }
}
```